# git --ff-only --squash rebase a branch to master

Tags: git

I am trying automate a git scenario wherein, I would like the commits from the branch, before it is merged into master to be

1) `rebased` on top of master.

2) It could be applied  `--ff-only` master. My guess is 1) covers this. Is that correct?

3) I  would like to squash it into a single commit that can be applied on top of master, and then merge it.

Git does not seem to provide commands with options to satisfy these requirements. Is there way for me to accomplish this goal?

`base_branch: M1->C1->C2
master_branch: M1->M2`

I want

`1. base_branch: M1->M2->C1->C2
2. base_branch: M1->M2->C1->C2
3. base_branch: M1->M2->C
4. merge
5. master_branch: M1->M2->C`

I'd like to maintain a clean, linear history of of my master, and all changes squashed to one commit. How can I accomplish this?

NB: If I convert the changes to patch, and apply on top of master, that accomplishes it. But I am looking for git way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

Git doesn't provide an automatic way to squash commits during a rebase in the way you're probably thinking of.  However, `git rebase` provides an an interactive rebase, which has the ability to squash commits.  Normally, interactive rebases are, well, interactive, and they'll spawn an editor.  However, you can specify a shell command in the environment variable `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR`, and it will be used to edit those commits.

So to do what you're wanting to do in a more automated manner, you could run `GIT_SEQUENCE_EDITOR="sed -i -e '2,\$s/^pick/squash/'" git rebase -i master`, which will modify the todo list to squash all of the commits together.  Git will then prompt you to coalesce the commit messages together into one.

If you're looking for a totally noninteractive situation, you can change the `squash` in the above command to `fixup`, and that will keep only the first commit message, discarding the others.

Note that on macOS, you may need to change `sed -i` to `sed -i ''` since its sed works a bit differently.